# Change jquery horizontal sliders to vertical

Tags: jquery, uislider, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling, rangeslider

I have this horizontal range slider widget and I want vertical option as well. Although I am able to change the orientation of the slide bars, I just can't seem to make the handles do the same. Any ideas on what I missed?

Visit: http://wp11004271.server-he.de/alloytoy3.7

Comment: This might help from what i can see your using jquery ui right?https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you could recreate this on codepen or fiddle so we have something to work with but from the looks of it all you would need to do is change your slider class `height` + `width` values to whatever you need.

Then on your javascript

```
        $("#slider-heatresist").slider({
            orientation: "vertical",             //Add this
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var value1 = (ui.value * 225 / 100).toFixed();
                var value2 = (ui.value * 225 / 100).toFixed();
                filter.sl7_min = value1;
                filter.sl7_max = value2;
                filterItems();
                if (ui.value == 0)
                    value1 = "Keine Auswahl";
                $("#heat_resistance").val(value1);

            },
            create: function (event, ui) {
                $("#heat_resistance").val("Keine Auswahl");
            }
        });//7
```

For more information on this you can refer to https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical

Comment: Yup, that did it. Seems I was adding the call to 'vertical' in the wrong area. Thanks a million!